# How search in multiple directories

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

start.bat

```
@echo off
CALL bat.bat "C:\Users\admin\Documents\test 2,C:\Users\admin\Documents\test 1" "*.xml *.txt *.html" "D:\Work\bat\batLog.txt"
```

bat.bat

```
for %%G  in (%1) do (
echo %%~G
    pushd "%%G"
    If Exist "%%G" (  
    for /R  %%H in ("%2") do (   
if %%~zH LSS %3 (
>>"%4" (
        echo %%~H
        echo %%~tH  
for /f "tokens=* delims=," %%i in ('type "%%~H"') do (
echo %%i
))) popd)))

pause
exit/b
```

why does not it go to the next directory? Echo only test 2

Comment: I would highly advise that you provide a detailed explanation as to what you are attempting to accomplish and update your `bat.bat` code so we can see how the other command line arguments are being used.

Comment: @Squashman done

Comment: You are missing a command line argument %3. The `PUSHD` should be after the `IF EXIST`  Since your command line arguments are quoted you should remove the quotes by using the tilde. `%~2`.  And you don't need quotes around the `%2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now a complete rewrite using your new code.  This should get you closer to what you want to do.  Hopefully I fixed all the other errors with your program.  I purposely indent my code so that I can see where a code block begins and ends. Much easier to see and understand how the code is working.

start.bat

```
@echo off
call bat.bat "C:\Users\admin\Documents\test 2,C:\Users\admin\Documents\test 1" "*.xml *.txt *.html" "20000" "D:\Work\bat\batLog.txt"
```

bat.bat

```
@echo off
REM %1 = List of Folders
REM %2 = List of file masks
REM %3 = File Size for comparison
REM %4 = Log File

set "folders=%1"
set "folders=%folders:,=","%"

for %%G in (%folders%) do (
    echo %%~G
    If Exist "%%~G" (  
        pushd "%%~G"
        for /R %%H in (%~2) do (   
            if %%~zH LSS %~3 (
                >>"%~4" (
                    echo %%~H
                    echo %%~tH  
                    for /f "tokens=* delims=," %%I in ('type "%%~H"') do (
                        echo %%~I
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        popd
    )
)

pause
exit/b
```

Comment: The fact is that after the paths I pass even more parameters that are needed for work. And the directory is not always two can be more or less. 

call bat.bat "C:\Users\admin\Documents\test 2,C:\Users\admin\Documents\test 1" "*.xml *.txt *.html" "D:\Work\bat\batLog.txt"

Comment: @Vaaassaa, I answered your question as it was presented. You can't put up a generalized question and expect an answer that will work for anything you throw at it.  Edit your question and update it with the EXACT technical specifications you need!

Comment: @Vaaassaa, I have updated my code using your new code examples.